# Improve the performance of query containing upper and nvl fucntion

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO tab2 NOLOGGING
SELECT 
   ID,
  ORG_NAME
FROM tab3
WHERE (( upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE '%MSOFT%'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE 'M SOFT'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE '%MISOFT%'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE 'MSN %'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE '%N APP%'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE '%NAPP%'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE '%NAPPE%'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE '%NAPPS%'
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE '%NEK%APPLIANCE%'
```

the above coding is taking too much time. Table tab3 is very huge.
The above is dynamic. Any alternatives for nvl?

Answer (score 1):

The line below

```
OR upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) LIKE 'M SOFT'
```

could be replaced with

```
OR ((orgname is not null  and upper(org_name) LIKE 'M SOFT')
    OR ((orgname is null  and upper(company_given) LIKE 'M SOFT')
```

Not sure it's faster.

Also you can try to run it once with subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       ID,
       ORG_NAME,
       upper(NVL(org_name,company_given)) as name_for_filter
    FROM tab3)
WHERE name_for_filter LIKE '%MSOFT%'
  OR name_for_filter LIKE 'M SOFT'
...
```

The best way would be to introduce a `name_for_filter` column in the table and fill it once with a trigger. Then the column could be used for the filtering

Answer (score 1):

This query is going to execute a full table scan of your table. You say that table is huge, so it's going to take a long time.

A normal index won't help because there are two columns in play. Even a  function-based index like this ...

```
create index fbi3 on tab3( upper(NVL(org_name, company_given) ))
```

... won't help because indexes are useless against a `like` filter with a wildcard at the front, and you have those:

```
LIKE '%NEK%APPLIANCE%'
```

If this is a one-time exercise I would suggest you swallow the time and wait for the statement to finish. But let's assume you want to do this kind of query often. If so, it's worth building infrastructure to support it.

1. A new column for the search criteria. Basically a column which is pre-populated with the arguments used in the functions. For 11g or higher make this a virtual column:

   `alter table tab3 add search_name as ( upper(NVL(org_name, company_given)));`

If using an older version of the database you will have to build a normal column and populate it with triggers.

2. Build a Text index on the `search_name` column. As it is short you can use a CTXCAT index, which will be maintained transactionally.
3. Then you need to rewrite the query to use `catsearch()` syntax instead of `like` operator. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#i1006741)

Comment: tab3 is a view. If i create a view on top of this view. {create view tab3_vw as select org_name, upper(NVL(org_name,company_given))  as org_name1 from tab3;} will this increase the performance if Select operation is done on this view.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, it's probably best to create a prepared search column. You could even remove the spaces to avoid a search for both `'N APP'` and `'NAPP'` for example (but that could lead to false positives in some cases).

On top of that you can remove the check for `%NAPPE%` and `%NAPPS%` because you already include records containing `%NAPP%`

It should be faster when using:

```
pseudocode:

   'MSN %'
or ('%SOFT%' and ('M SOFT' or '%MSOFT%' or '%MISOFT%'))
or ('%APP%' and ('%N APP%' or '%NAPP%' or '%NEK%APPLIANCE%'))
```

If `SOFT` or `APP` is not found there is no need to check for the others containing the same word - the `and` will avoid that if the first part is already `false`.

If this is just an example and those parameters are variable, you could write some code to optimize those search terms (unless the SQL server already does that).